# Deploying as a standalone page

Tags: deployment, elm

During the development process, I've been using `elm-reactor` to test my one-page Elm application. But for production deployment, I would like to just store the compiler's output as static files on a webserver.

How do I compile an Elm page into a standalone pair of HTML + Javascript files?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Use `elm-make` to compile your Elm application to `elm.js` (target the module that defines `main`).
2. Create your own HTML file that includes that script and a script in the body that executes `Elm.<Module-that-defines-main>.fullscreen()`

### Example

App.elm

```
module App where

import Text
import Signal
import Graphics.Element (Element)

main : Signal Element
main = "Hello World!" |> Text.asText |> Signal.constant
```

`elm-make App.elm` (creates `elm.js`)

App.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="elm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">Elm.App.fullscreen()</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: saved my day, although I use elm-brunch for compiling (integrating with Phoenix) the Elm.fullscreen advice was invaluable

Answer (score 8):

The answer to [this ticket](https://github.com/evancz/start-app/issues/15) on the github project page is also quite helpful:

> Finally, use this command to compile the file into a single, stand-alone HTML file.

```
$ elm make start-test.elm --output index.html
```

Comment: The link in this answer is dead.

Comment: This is correct, and I can't find where the author has moved the issue to - looks like it's been deleted, which is a pity.